# Как вернутся в начало?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import threading
import time

sec = 2 # время обратного отсчет

def c():
    for i in range(sec, 0, -1):
        z_z =100

        print('Осталось %d секунд' % i, z_z)
        time.sleep(1)

    for i in range(sec, 0, -1):
        z_z =200

        print('Осталось %d секунд' % i, z_z)
        time.sleep(1)

    for i in range(sec, 0, -1):
        z_z =300

        print('Осталось %d секунд' % i, z_z)
        time.sleep(1)

    for i in range(sec, 0, -1):
        z_z =400

        print('Осталось %d секунд' % i, z_z)
        time.sleep(1)

t = threading.Thread(target=c, args=())
print('c')
t.start()
```

Comment: Вернутся откуда в начало чего? Ничего не понятно

Comment: нужно чтобы скрипт в потоке  работал бесконечно

Comment: Ну, завернуть требуемый код в бесконечный цикл while True, например?

Comment: andreymal Огромное спасибо дошло)

Comment: @scat, если разобрались - добавьте ответом, а не исправляйте код в вопросе